how to correctly translate with i18next?
I'm trying to use i18next with Gatsby/React plugin.
My Parent components (some page)
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./child";
import { useI18next } from "gatsby-plugin-react-i18next";

export default function ParentComponent({ data }) {
  const { languages, changeLanguage } = useI18next();
  return (
    <>
      {languages.map((item) => (
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            changeLanguage(lang);
          }}
          key={item}
        >
          {item.toUpperCase()}
        </button>
      ))}
      <ChildComponent data={data} />
    </>
  );
}

export const query = graphql`
  // graphql query
`;


Child component:
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export default function ChildComponent({ data }) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <>
      <p>{data.text}</p>
      {data.content.map((item, index) => (
        <h5 key={index}>{t(item)}</h5>
      ))}
    </>
  );


And a pair of jsons in locales:
en:
{
  "text": "Welcome!",
  "content": [
    { "subheader": "subheader1" },
    { "subheader": "subheader 2" },
    { "subheader": "subheader3" }
  ]
}

de:
{
  "text": "Willkommen!",
  "content": [
    { "suhbeader": "Untertitel 1" },
    { "suhbeader": "Untertitel 2" },
    { "suhbeader": "Untertitel 3" }
  ]
}

The biggest strange thing is that translation works without t() or "Trans" component. Should I use t() like this or no?
<p>{t(data.text)}</p>

Which way is correct in my case? "Trans", t() from useTranslation, something else?

Where is data from?

From graphql response. It's a common practice: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/
On every page I can have graphql query to locales (or/and something else), and result is 'data' object.
